# OntouchEvent And Admob

Tags: android, admob, touch-event

I have a counter on my application which increases on Touch, on the same page i also have admob ads. But if the user click on the ads the counter still increases rather than going on the ads page. 
Please give me suggestions on how to overcome this problem.
Thanks
Here's the code for onTouch:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        try {

            if (nearCount >=0 ) {


                tv.setText("" + nearCount++);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);


}
```

Comment: How are you capturing onTouch? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

Increment the counter when the View receiving focus isn't an adview :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !adView.isFocused())
        try {

            if (nearCount >=0 ) {


                tv.setText("" + nearCount++);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);


}
```

Comment: onTouch is there on full page on my activity, so if user touches anywhere on screen the counter increases. I want that when the user touches on the ad area, the ad should be opened, but instead the counter is increasing if someone clicked on ad.

Comment: Ok. The don't increment the counter if the view is an adview. Check my updated answer